# Determine the characteristic polynomial

Tags: differential

The problem can be seen below. I understand how to find the poles and modes and the zero-input solution but I have two questions about the characteristic polynomial.

First, do I need to divide by 6 first or is it defined as having a coefficient of 1 in front of the second derivative? I haven't found a definite way to handle a coefficient in front of f(t).

Second, when finding the characteristic polynomial, do I neglect the $$ -sy(0^{-}) - y'(0^{-}) $$ and similar terms and just use $$ s^{2}\hat{Y}(s)+2s\hat{Y}(s)-8\hat{Y}(s) $$ ?

> Determine the characteristic polynomial P(s), characteristic poles, characteristic modes, and the zero-input solution for each of the LTIC systems described below.
>
> $$ \frac{d^{2}y}{dt^{2}} + 2\frac{dy}{dt} -8y(t) = 6f(t) ,\ y(0^{-})= 0 ,\ y'(0^{-})=1 $$

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The characteristic polynomial is 
$$s^2 + 2s -8.$$

*Explanation:* Characteristic polynomials are defined in linear algebra as the following: For an \$n \times n\$ matrix \$A\$ the characteristic polynomial is
$$p_A(t) = det(A-tI)$$
where \$I\$ is the \$n \times n\$ identity matrix.

Your original differential equation is the same as the system of differential equations
$$y_1'(t) + 2y_1(t) - 8y_0(t) =  6 f(t)$$
$$y_1(t) = y_0'(t)$$

with initial conditions \$y_0(0^{-}) = 0\$ and  \$y_1(0^{-}) =1\$.

Writing \$\vec{y}(t) = \begin{bmatrix} y_1(t)\\ y_0(t) \end{bmatrix}\$ we end up with the matrix differential equation
$$\vec{y}(t)' = \begin{bmatrix} -2 & 8 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \vec{y}(t) + \begin{bmatrix} 6f(t) \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}.$$

The characteristic polynomial of the differential equation is defined as the characteristic polynomial of the coefficient matrix $$A = \begin{bmatrix} -2 & 8 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$
which is $$p_A(t) = t^2 +2t-8.$$